# The virtual machine cannot restart. The current virtual machine state is RoleStateUnknown

Tags: azure

I'd be grateful if anyone can shed some light on this issue I am having.

Having succesfully created a Windows 2008 VHD using VirtualBox and uploaded to Azure with csupload, created an image I ran into the following problems.

When provising the VM for the first time, the VM goes to "stopped" and the following error appears.

"The virtual machine cannot restart. The current virtual machine state is RoleStateUnknown.

Browser: 5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.3; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)".

I tried to restart the VM and the status remains in Provisioning (running).

Am I running into these problems because of the preview and would you recommend that Azure is not fit for purpose for provisioning Virtual Machines at this stage?

Any help, advice or guidance would be very much appreciated.

Regards,

Chris

Answer (score 2):

While you have done everything correctly it is possible you are hitting a known issue in platform which could cause this problem. The problem is described as following:

[Machine cannot restart due to RoleStateUnknown](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/WAVirtualMachinesforWindows/thread/5b7063d7-51b4-4258-bff5-2269dd385f85)

My suggestion will be to try the suggestion given in the link above and post your troubleshooting details to [Windows Azure Virtual Machines for Windows](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/WAVirtualMachinesforWindows/threads) to get someone to assist you further.

Alternatively to expedite your resolution, you can try to use an image from the Gallery and install your stuff to get it working for you.

Answer (score 0):

Did you sysprep the machine? This is a requirement if you upload your image:

> [Step 4: Prepare the image to be uploaded](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/windows/common-tasks/upload-a-vhd/#prepimage):  Before the image can be uploaded to Windows Azure, it must be
>   generalized by using the Sysprep command.

If you're still having issues I suggest you take a look at this topic which describes the most common issues when uploading your own image: [Common issues - uploaded VHDs](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/WAVirtualMachinesforWindows/thread/66c8c2d3-19bb-4248-a36f-d2dfe9742dd3)

Comment: Yes I did "Sysprep".  I'll take a look at Common Issues.  Thank you

Comment: I still am unable to upload a custom image.  I can't only assume that this functionality is still in beta?